# Excel : Increment Row number on fill right

Tags: excel, fill

When one "Fills right in excel" , the Column name updates

eg.

1st cell
is
=A2

If I fill right the next cell will be =B2

But rather than the column incrementing I want to increment the row number

so 1st cell is
=A2

The cell on its right is
=A3

how do i do that?

Comment: I ended up using VLOOKUPTABLE but will try the below and let you guys know.

Answer (score 3):

If you're putting the first formula in B2 then

```
=OFFSET($A$2,COLUMN()-2,0)
```

The -2 part is because we're starting in column B.  You need to change it for whatever column you're actually starting in such that the second argument equal zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `INDIRECT` function. Suppose we want formulas in cells B1, C1, D1... that should reference A2, A3, A4... Starting in cell B2 we can enter:

```
=INDIRECT("R[" & COLUMN(RC)-1 & "]C1", FALSE)
```

In cell B2, this will render as:

```
=INDIRECT("R[1]C1", FALSE)
```

In this situation, I'm using R1C1 format. The second parameter to the `INDIRECT` function tells the function to use R1C1 format. The function itself (again in cell B2), says "give me what is in the cell that is one row down and the first column". In the original formula, by basing the row value on the current column number, it will update the formula to a new row as you fill right.

Now, if you are asking if there is a way to do this using the GUI like say using the Fill box with the mouse, the answer is no. There is no means to transpose the fill using the GUI.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get ```=COLUMN(RC)``` accepted as a valid formula (Excel 2011 for Mac) so the first formula fails.

Comment: @Orwellophile - This works even on a Mac *if you enable R1C1 reference style*.

Comment: and how can one do that (and have it saved with the spreadsheet so it will works when the next person uses it)?

Comment: @Orwellophile - It works great as long as someone doesn't change the relative structure of the spreadsheet. As I often say, _The nice thing about spreadsheets is that you can do anything anywhere. The bad thing about spreadsheets is that you can do anything anywhere._